# How do I reflect a matrix in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, matplotlib

[image]

I have created a matrix in matplotlib. As you can see it only covers half of the matrix.
Is there anyway that I can reflect the points onto the other side of the matrix so I can fill the whole matrix?

generated using `imshow`

Comment: How are you generating this image (`imshow`, `pcolor`, drawing patches by hand)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Mr.E.'s answer is (almost) correct, I felt like it needed a complete minimal working example. The trick is to plot `A + A.T`. However, when you do so you'll double count the diagonal, thus you have to subtract that part out.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

# Create a sample matrix like your image
A = np.random.random((100,100)) * .52
A = np.rint(A)
for idx in np.ndindex(A.shape):
    if idx[0]>idx[1]: A[idx] = 0

plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(A,interpolation='none')

# Make a new matrix B = A + A.T - diagonal(A)
B = A + A.T - np.diag(np.diag(A))
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.imshow(B,interpolation='none')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: For large matrices, it's more efficient to do `A += A.T; A[np.diag_indices_from(A)] /= 2`.